# Excel - find values searching columns first, than rows from found column

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

[image]

I have the above table.

First I need to search the columns, based on pipe's diameter. For example I need to search a 3/4" pipe. (this is found on column D).

Second, I need to search the rows from this found column (column D) for the debit through this pipe.

For example a debit of 0.67. As you can see in the table, in column D there is not a debit = 0.67 so I need a function to return me the values of 0.63 (cell D5) and 0.77 (cell D6) in two different fields.

Is there a function (combination of functions) I can use?

My second example: diameter to search is 1 1/4", debit is 4.4
Diameter 1 1/4" is to be found in column F.
Than debit 4.4 is not in column F so I need values 4.3 (cell F9) and 4.59 (cell F10) to be returned.

I tried =INDEX($AG$2:$AT$31,MATCH(W4,$AG$2:$AG$31,0),MATCH(Y4,$AG$2:$AT$2,0)) but this doe not returns me the needed value.
Also I tried =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($Y6,$A$1:$N$1,0)),"","") in order to get first the required column and after somehow to get the rows values with same no success.

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: I tried =INDEX($AG$2:$AT$31,MATCH(W4,$AG$2:$AG$31,0),MATCH(Y4,$AG$2:$AT$2,0))     and      tried to get the column name first =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($Y7,$A$1:$N$1,0)),"","")   but with no success

Comment: Could you add this to your main post as this will help others understand what it is you tried to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost got it.  `MATCH()` can only lookup a value in a single row or column.  `INDEX()` can pull a value out of a table, and usually, you use MATCH() to specify the row number and column number, by looking for the right row and column header.

Your problem is a bit tricky, because you don't have row headers that `MATCH()` can use.  So you need to (first) get the appropriate column, and then match a number in that column.

Let's build up the formula by parts and it'll be easier to see what's going on.  `INDEX(array,row_num,col_num)` will return a column, all you have to do is leave out the row_num.  Say the pipe diameter you're looking for is in B25, as in the screenshot below.  Then this formula will return the appropriate column of the data table:

`INDEX(B2:J20,,MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0))`

You can check this by highlighting the formula in the formula bar and hitting F9. That will show you a list of the values in the column that has B25 as its header.

Next we want to find the debit in that column, so we use the column in a `MATCH()` formula:

`MATCH(C25,INDEX(B2:J20,,MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0)),1)`

Note that for this outer `MATCH()`, we're using a match_type of 1 instead of 0.  Match_type 0 forces an exact match, but match_type 1 will return the nearest lower value if it can't find an exact match.  And that's just what you want.

Now, the only problem is that this formula just returns the **position** of the match it found, not the actual value. But now we know the column and the row, so we can wrap it in another `INDEX()` to get the actual value of the debit:

`=INDEX(B2:J20,MATCH(C25,INDEX(B2:J20,,MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0)),1),MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0))`

Here the last `MATCH()` specifies the col_num, and the first one specifies the row_num.  This formula is in E24 in the picture below.  It didn't find an exact match for a debit of 1.7, so it returned the next lower number 1.59.

[image]

We can get the next higher debit just by adding 1 to the row_num:

`=INDEX(B2:J20,MATCH(C25,INDEX(B2:J20,,MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0)),1)+1,MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0))`

And we can have it return a blank if an exact match was found:

`=IF(F24<>"Match",INDEX(B2:J20,MATCH(C25,INDEX(B2:J20,,MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0)),1)+1,MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0)),"")`

The formulas in F24 and F25 are:

`=IF(E24=C25,"Match","Next Lower")`

`=IF(E24=C25,"","Next Higher")`

I hope this helps.  Best of luck.

**EDIT:** To return the corresponding values from Column A, we can use OFFSET().  Offset starts at a specified cell (we'll use A1 here), and goes down a specified number of rows.  For the number of rows, we'll use the same expression we used to get the position of debit:  `MATCH(C25,INDEX(B2:J20,,MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0)),1)`

The whole formula is:

`=OFFSET(A1,MATCH(C25,INDEX(B2:J20,,MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0)),1),0)`

And we can get the next higher value by simply adding 1 to the number of rows, as before:

`=OFFSET(A1,MATCH(C25,INDEX(B2:J20,,MATCH(B25,B1:J1,0)),1)+1,0)`

Comment: PERFECT! this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.

Comment: @Bandersnatch,, I've tested both the Formulas and if I put 3/4" & 1.7, it produces #ref error, when I put 3/4" & 0.67 then I got 0.77 for both and the expected result is 0.63 as lower and 0.77 as higher !

Comment: @Rajesh S - my test works just fine, 3/4" & 1.7 returns 1.59 & 1.8 as expected. Same, 3/4" & 0.67 returns 0.63 & 0.77 as expected. Also I tried other values, did not notice any errors. Maybe you input something wrong while doing the tests?

Comment: @Gabriel, I've tested both the Formula with correct parameter,,, no wrong entries,,, could you post the Screen Shot along with the Formula?

Comment: @Rajesh S - see my post bellow, I don't know how to post images here

Comment: @Rajesh, a formula is working correctly for two people, but you "test" it and get an error.  That doesn't surprise me at all.

Comment: @Bandersnatch, could you please help me out with one more thing? Now, once we found (as per our example) 1.59 and 1.86 the next lower and the next higher, how can I get in two other separate cells the value from cell A11 and A12?  What I mean is the values from column A corresponding to the rows containing the next lower and next higher, for each search.  Thank you

Comment: I'll be back at my computer later.  You could do this with [OFFSET()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-offset-function). Start in A1 (the "reference"), and use a column offset of 0, and the row_num portion of the formula for the row offset. Add 1 for the next value. I'll check back later.  Good luck! :-)

Comment: @Gabriel, forgot to tag you. See above.

Comment: @Bandersnatch - thank you, thank you again. I was trying for the last 5 days to figure out the solution - you helped me out in no time. GREAT !!

Answer (score 1):

@Rajesh S  I am posting here two screens shots as per your request.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

*Your problem could be solved with a two-way lookup. You need to find the value where criteria specify the column and row.*

**Check the screen shot below.**

[image]

The formula below finds the value in the row beginning with **0.04** and in the column beginning with **3/4"**.  The result is **0.63**.

`=INDEX(B2:E10,MATCH(A5,A2:A10,0),MATCH(D1,B1:E1,0))`

**Note,** if my solution is not what you're looking for, just comment below.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, it is a Two Way Lookup. The first criteria will be the pipe diameter (3/4" as my example). The second criteria is NOT related to the first column (it is not match(A5,A2:A10,0).) The second criteria I have to enter it in a cell beside my table (debit of 0.67 as my example) and the function will search now on the column D (as 3/4" was found on column D based on first search criteria). The second criteria will "find" that 0.67 is located between 0.63 and 0.77 and will return beside the table, in two different cells, the two values 0.63 and 0.77.